# Taxonomy terms are not linked to nodes

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type with a field term reference to a vocabulary using selection list widget.
When i fill the content type, i get in the output the term selected.
But i click on that term i have the message :
There is currently no content classified with this term.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have multi language site.
I suggest you use the [Taxonomy display](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display) module, here is a quote from its project page:

> The taxonomy display module allows administrative configurable term
>   display pages. This allows administrators to override the default
>   presentation of taxonomy term pages per vocabulary through the
>   [taxonomy term page's manage display form](https://www.drupal.org/node/1254878).